# JavaFX BarChart Scrollable?

Tags: java, javafx

how would I go about making a barchart to be scrollable?
I been trying to use the a scrollPane with the barchart pane inside it.

so far this is what i have:

```
final BarChart chartPane = chart.getGraph();
chartScrollPane.setContent(chartPane);
chartScrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
```

The chartPane is 1200px wide, and the chartScrollPane is 800px.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the width of the BarChart to a larger value. When the chart is embedded in a ScrollPane it will care about the scrollbars.

For example:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 800, 600);
chartPane.setPrefWidth(20000);
chartPane.setMinWidth(20000);
scrollPane.setContent(chartPane);
```

Comment: A better idea would be to count your bars and say every bar needs for example 100px and then chartPane.setPrefWidth(bar_count * 100)